# Query: exclude if starts with

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is it possible to exclude every item that starts with a specific string?

for example:

```
query.doesNotStartWith('content', '#');
```

That should exclude every item where the content filed starts with the string "#".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex can be a little tricky with Parse.com and you need to be careful when using it because of scalability concerns. Fortunately, prefix regex is quick and this can be accomplished using a [compound query](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-compound-queries) which only counts as 1 API request.

First, create the "inner" query where the content ***does*** start with the specific string.

```
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query("YourClass");
innerQuery.startsWith("content", "#");
```

Next, create the "outer" query which we can use to filter out the regex matches using [doesNotMatchKeyInQuery](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#doesNotMatchKeyInQuery).

```
var outerQuery = new Parse.Query("YourClass");
outerQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("content", "content", innerQuery);
```

Cheers,
Russell